# Heroku Application won't deploy - "No such file to load -- spec_helper"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

When I attempt to open my Heroku application after deploying, I get the following error:

**An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.**
a
Here are the heroku logs:

```
2013-12-02T17:20:35.252948+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-12-02T17:20:39.605491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 34424 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': No such
 file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in
require'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.609423+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2013-12-02T17:21:00.609423+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-12-02T17:21:00.609423+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-12-02T17:21:00.609423+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.1 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:34424
2013-12-02T17:21:00.609423+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in
require'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_depe
ndency'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/user_spec.r
b:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_depe
ndency'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on
'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611261+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_o
r_load'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_d
ependency'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_loa
d!'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module
:Finisher>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.611643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/
ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612216+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612045+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612603+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612603+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612603+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-12-02T17:21:00.612830+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-12-02T17:21:02.231250+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-12-02T17:21:02.244006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed

C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's hard to see among the whole log output, but the real error message you're getting is `No such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)` and that's coming from `app/models/user_spec.rb:1`.

Is there a reason you put your `user_spec` file in your `app/models` directory? Usually, model tests go in a `spec/models` directory. By default, every file under the `app` directory is loaded by your application when it boots, and normally you don't want to load test files in your application.

Comment: I made this change, however I'm still getting the same error. I should add that when I do 'heroku run rake db:migrate', the rake aborts and it tells me that multiple migrations have the name "CreateMicroposts". Could this be it? How would I fix that?

Comment: I doubt you're getting the exact same error, but it probably looks similar with all the stack trace junk around the actual message. Not being able to migrate could certainly keep your app from starting. You need to rename one of your CreateMicroposts migrations to be called something else.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your app is crashing. Does it run in development? Try running `rails s -e production` on your development machine for an easier debugging.